# $f(z) = z^2$ over $\{z\in \mathbb{C}; |z|=1\}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I need to find the complex plot of:

$f(z) = z^2$ over $C = \{z\in \mathbb{C}; |z|=1\}$

So I parametrized $C$ as this:

$$z = \cos t + i\sin t$$

Then:

$$f(z) = z^2 = (\cos t +i\sin t)^2 = \cos^2(t)+2i\sin t\cos t -\sin^2(t) = $$

$$\cos^2 t-\sin^2t + 2i\sin t\cos t = \cos(2t) + i\sin (2t)$$

So the graph of the domain and the image are both the circunference or radius $1$?

Also, is there a place where I can give a domain, a complex function and see the image of this domain in another complex plane? I've tried wolfram alpha and geogebra but I couldn't do it.

Comment: That's correct, squaring a complex number on the unit circle just doubles its angle, so $z \mapsto z^2$ is a surjective function from the unit circle to itself.  Using polar form, you can see the effect of squaring more easily: $$(e^{i\theta})^2 = e^{2i\theta}$$